# Is it good to use WebViews in React Native from Security Perspective?

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-navigation, react-native-webview

I was going through [this](https://www.gluu.org/blog/webviews-are-bad-use-appauth/) link and they mentioned that:

> In a WebView, any malicious code in the page has the same rights as the application. This means you need to make sure to only load trusted content. But there is another risk–a malicious app may also have access to browser content (like cookies) and may snoop passwords or intercept OAuth codes.

I was wondering why would Facebook implement WebView then if it had security vulnerabilities.

Is it good to use WebViews in React native mobile application?

Comment: Did you find an answer?